# MySql query error, can anyone equivalent query of this?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, inner-join

I tried this

```
select posts.id, posts.title
from posts
inner join (
    select post_id,max(created)
    from comments
    group by post_id
    order by max(created) DESC ) as foo
on posts.id=foo.post_id
order by foo.max(created) DESC;
```

Error

```
ERROR 1630 (42000): FUNCTION foo.max does not exist.
Check the 'Function Name Parsing and Resolution' section in the Reference Manual
```

Tables

```
mysql> describe comments;
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| post_id  | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| name     | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| email    | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| body     | varchar(500) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| mark     | tinyint(4)   | NO   |     | 1       |                |
| created  | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| modified | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)



mysql> describe posts;
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| user_id     | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| title       | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| body        | text         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| category_id | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| tags        | varchar(50)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| mark        | tinyint(4)   | NO   |     | 1       |                |
| created     | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| modified    | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I need to get the posts with latest comments.

Comment: You have an `ORDER BY` clause in your subquery: is this intentional? If yes, what effect do you suppose it will have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select posts.id, posts.title
from posts
inner join (
    select post_id, max(created) as most_recent
    from comments
    group by post_id) as foo
on posts.id=foo.post_id
order by most_recent DESC;
```

The problem is that `max(created)` in the subquery should have a name. An you do not need to sort in a subquery.

Answer (score 3):

You have using the wrong reference here :-

```
foo.max(created)
```

It should be :-

```
max(foo.created)
```

The error message is already reveal where is the problem,
you should always debug on the error message when you encounter an error

But you did not return a column created for alias foo, so :-

```
select posts.id, posts.title
from posts
inner join 
(
  select post_id,max(created) AS created
  from comments
  group by post_id 
) as foo
on posts.id=foo.post_id
order by created DESC; <-- you don't need max
```

Comment: I got this error, ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'foo.created' in 'order clause

Comment: please check again your sql in your question, the foo. is aliased at the outer sql, for the inner sql, you can just remove foo.

Comment: Post the complete sql query, it's being confusing.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `foo.max` function.

Did you mean:

```
SELECT posts.id,
       posts.title
FROM   posts
       INNER JOIN (SELECT post_id,
                          created
                   FROM   comments
                   GROUP  BY post_id
                   ORDER  BY Max(created) DESC) AS foo
         ON posts.id = foo.post_id
ORDER  BY Max(foo.created) DESC;
```

Comment: I got this error, ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'foo.created' in 'order clause